# How to append pages of data using jQuery and Django pagination?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, pagination

I am using Django's inbuilt `pagination` to paginate the data and displaying in the template. I now would like to implement jQuery to load and append pages to the template using ajax. How do I do it using jQuery?

I was using [django-endless-pagination](https://github.com/frankban/django-endless-pagination) before, but since it adds the entries by JavaScript my lightbox to display images does not catch the image elements and only displays the entry which was loaded at first request.

views.py:

```
def snaps(request):
    snapgroup_list = SnapGroup.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(snapgroup_list, 1)

    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except:
        page = 1
    try:
        snapgroup = paginator.page(page)
    except(EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        snapgroup = paginator.page(page)

    index = snapgroup.number - 1  # edited to something easier without index
    max_index = len(paginator.page_range)
    start_index = index - 3 if index >= 3 else 0
    end_index = index + 3 if index <= max_index - 3 else max_index
    page_range = paginator.page_range[start_index:end_index]

    return render(request, 'snaps.html', {
        'page_range': page_range,
        'snapgroup':snapgroup
        })
```

snaps.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block main_content %}

<div id="main_content">
    <div id="snap_wrapper" class="container">
        <hr>
        {% if snapgroup.object_list.count > 0 %} 
            {% include 'snapgroups.html' %}
        {% else %}
            <li><p>No SNAPS yet!</p></li>
            <span class="clear_both"></span>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="prev_next">
        {% if snapgroup.has_previous %}
          <a class="prev btn btn-info" href="?page={{snapgroup.previous_page_number}}">Prev</a>
        {% endif %}
        {% if snapgroup.has_next %}
          <a class="next btn btn-info" href="?page={{snapgroup.next_page_number}}">Next</a>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="pages">
          <ul>
          {% for pg in page_range %}
            {% if snapgroup.number == pg %}
              <li><a href="?page={{pg}}" class="btn btn-default">{{pg}}</a></li>
            {% else %}
              <li><a href="?page={{pg}}" class="btn">{{pg}}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <span class="clear_both"></span>
    </div>  
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

snapgroups.html:

```
{% for sg in snapgroup.object_list %}
    <h4 id="combination" class="snap_date">{{sg.date|date:'l'}}, {{sg.date}}</h4>
    <ul>
    {% for snap in sg.snap_set.all %}
        <li><a href="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{snap.image}}" data-imagelightbox="f"><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{snap.image}}" alt="{{snap.caption}}" /></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
        <span class="clear_both"></span>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: personally I wouldn't use Django's pagination if you want to use Ajax.  There are plenty of JavaScript pagers that will work very well with JSON data sent down from the Django Server.  Or if you wanted you could use Django-Rest-Framework which also has built in pagination, but it would be much more efficient to hit the endpoints via ajax.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes Yes, that would be better. But I am just learning, would you please show me how to do it. Its ok if I had to change the code if I am getting the result I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will still use [django-endless-pagination](https://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (Its the best ajax based pagination plugin out there), and the solution for your problem would be to recall the `lightbox` init after the pagination request completed, read more on [callbacks](https://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/javascript.html#attaching-callbacks):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hookup_lightbox(){
        $( selector ).imageLightbox();
    }

    $.endlessPaginate({
        onCompleted: function(context, fragment) {
            // hookup lightbox
            hookup_lightbox();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this solution is the answer suits the original question better. (Though I would suggest a solution using Django Rest Framework like @ChrisHawkes mentioned already)

Answer (score 9):

I'd show you with an example app. Since you're just learning, this will be helpful if you actually make one such app with the code below.

I've tried to keep the code as minimum as I could.

*models.py*

```
class Article(...):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    photo = models.ImageField(...)
```

*views.py*

```
import json

def article_ajax(request):
    TOTAL = 10
    OFFSET = request.GET.get('offset', 0)
    END = offset + TOTAL
    # TOTAL means how many articles to load
    # in a single request

    # to understand OFFSET and END, consider this:
    # mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    # mylist[2:5] outputs => [3,4,5]
    # Above 2 is OFFSET and 5 is END

    articles = Article.objects.all()[OFFSET:END]

    json_list = []
    for article in articles:
        json_list.append({
            'title': article.title, 'photo_url': article.photo.url
        })

    data = json.dumps(json_list)

    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

*urls.py*

```
...
url(r'^ajax/articles/$', 'myapp.views.article_ajax'),
...
```

*articles.html*

The script also contains infinite scrolling code, too :)

```
<!-- All articles will be loaded in following div -->
<div id="ArticlesDiv"></div>

<script>
var articleOffset = 0;

var articleLoader = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/articles/?offset=' + articleOffset,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0, total = data.length; i < total; i++) {
                    var compile_data;
                    compile_data = '<h1>' + data[i].title + '</h1>\
                        <img src="' + data[i]photo_url + '">';

                    $('#ArticlesDiv').append(compile_data);
                }

                /* update the offset */
                articleOffset += 10
            } else {
                $('#ArticlesDiv').append('No articles found');
            }
        }
    });
}

/* Infinite scrolling for fetching articles */
var $window = $(window);
function prodScrollPosition() {
    var distance = $window.scrollTop() + $window.height();
    if ($('body').height() <= distance && $('#ArticlesDiv')) {
        articleLoader();
    }
}

$window.scroll(prodScrollPosition).scroll();

/* Manually initiate the first ajax request */
articleLoader();
</script>
```

Comment: Wow this is very nice. I am just confused on how to do it while referencing through a foreign key, with `_set.all`. Since in the template I am looping through each `SnapGroup` and then again loop through each `Snap` of one `SnapGroup`. How do I do that? Will you please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: @Robin I don't think it's a good idea to display all `SnapGroups` and all `Snaps` in one page. It's too database intensive and will slow your application down if there are too many rows in the database.

What I'd advise to do is display all `SnapGroups` in one page. Then user will choose one `SnapGroup` to see the `Snaps` in it. This approach is faster and won't hit the database with unnecessary queries.

Comment: This is a great answer! Only thing I had to change was to do a JSON.parse(data) to convert the incoming JSON data into a Javascript-object and get the correct length from it (otherwise I would get the number of characters).